# Converting DataTime? to DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code. Which reads a date time from a sql database however this allows nulls. So there for the data type i am getting is DateTime? I need to convert this to DateTime within the code. I cannot change the allow nulls option on the Database.

I have tried the following but does not work

```
DateTime  Date  = startsUps.FirstOrDefault().DATE_TIME;

string ShortDate = Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Any idea on how to convert datetime? to datetime would be great.

Comment: Can you not access it on the Date.Value property?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` has a `Value` property of type `T`. It's not too hard to find it in the manual. But I don't see anything nullable in the example code.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().DATE_TIME` throws a `null` reference exception if `.FirstOrDefault() == null`. You should use a select `DATE_TIME` or use `First()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
DateTime newDate = null;
try 
{
    var obj = startsUps.FirstOrDefault();
    newDate = obj.DATE_TIME ?? DateTime.Now;
}
catch 
{
    //If FirstOrDefault() is null do something else
    newDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

The `??` means that if the left side is `null` a new DateTime will be created at the right side ( Now ).

Comment: So... what happens if `startsUps` is empty?

Comment: Remove the new keyword before DateTime.Now.

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is a static property, not a type. You don't need (and can't have) `new` before it.

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().DATE_TIME` throws a `null` reference exception if `.FirstOrDefault() == null`. You should use a select `DATE_TIME` or use `First()` instead.

Comment: in his question he is talking about the DATE_TIME that can allow null. So i was pointing that out. But indeed if the `FirstOrDefault() == null` you will get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are sure that there are no null values in the database**, then you can cast to your desired type:

```
var startUp = startsUps.FirstOrDefault();
if(startUp != null) {
    DateTime dateTimeNotNull  = (DateTime)startUp.DATE_TIME;
}
```

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault().DATE_TIME` throws a `null` reference exception if `.FirstOrDefault() == null`. You should use a select `DATE_TIME` or use `First()` instead.

Comment: you're right (change the code) but I was assuming that this is not the problem related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for null and asign the datetime from Database only if it is not null.

```
DateTime finalDt = DateTime.Now;
if(yourDate != null)
   finalDt = yourDate;
```

Or

You can use Null-coalescing  operator

```
DateTime finalDt = yourDate ?? DateTime.Now;
```